# MVC3 Count of checked Checkboxes

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my View I want to see in a editor field the Count of checked Checkboxes!
How can I put my Request?

Controller:
How can I convert that in the Controller? 
  //

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    } 

    //
    // POST: /Projects/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(PPM_Project project)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Project.Add(project);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        ViewBag.Status = new SelectList(new string[] { "----------", "running", "on hold", "finished", "not started", "cancelled" });
        return View(project);
    }
```

View:
What is to change in the View?

```
   <div class="editor-label-AI">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Anzahl_Betroffene_BU_Einheiten)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field-AZB">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Anzahl_Betroffene_BU_Einheiten)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Anzahl_Betroffene_BU_Einheiten)
    </div>
```

There I want to see the Count of checked Checkboxes!

Thank´s for help!

Comment: Please improve your question, problem is not clear. Please remove unnecessary code and rephrase a problem.

Comment: where is your checkboxes actually?

Answer (score 1):

Provided I understand your question correctly: you need a text box to update based on how many checkboxes are checked...

You will need to do this in JavaScript if you're using MVC. I whipped up an example which showcases this functionality which can probably be easily adapted to your project.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/8uvs8/)

[image]

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />

<div class="editor-field-AZB">
    <input id="count" value="0" />
</div>

<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
var countInput = document.getElementById('count');
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].onchange = countCheckboxes;
}

function countCheckboxes() {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) 
            count++;
    }
    countInput.value = count;
}
countCheckboxes();
```